error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/node/ts4.8/url'
when i'm building my App i got this error
Error: node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.d.ts:9:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/node/ts4.8/url'.  9   

/// <reference types="@types/node/ts4.8/url" />                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     

Error: node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/interface.d.ts:9:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/node/ts4.8/url'.  9   

/// <reference types="@types/node/ts4.8/url" /> 

i installed @types/node and @angular-devkit/schematics and nothing works.
my package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/android-permissions": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/http": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/ionic-webview": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/keyboard": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/native-audio": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/network": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/screen-orientation": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^6.6.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.7.3",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/screen-orientation": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.5.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova": "^12.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^12.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^8.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.1.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.2.1",
    "js-sha3": "^0.9.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.1.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.7.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

and tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  }
}

can someone please help me, i don't know what to do?
i deleted the line in node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.d.ts:9:23 and node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/interface.d.ts:9:23 then it works, but not in docker.

Try setting skipLibCheck in your tsconfig. Or you can change @types/node version to ^18 in your package.json.

Having the same issue after the project migrating from Angular 15 to 17. So far only skipLibCheck seems to help.

Remove "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.3.2" and delete node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics.

in tsconfig.json ==>
add =>
"skipLibCheck": true
